# wrong render on mobile while using foundation 5

Tags: android, html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

this is my situation, I have a foundation 5 website in local that works fine, however when I put a set of pages on the server to test on mobile (samsung galaxy considered medium device) a part of the content doesnt extend as supposed. this is the structure of my masterpage file:

```
<!-- MasterPage Structure -->
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="hide-for-medium-down large-3 columns" data-equalizer-watch></div>
    <div class="small-12 large-7 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-for-medium-down large-2 columns" data-equalizer-watch></div>
</div>
```

and this is one of my content page which renders bad on my phone, I'll explain what it does inside the code as some portion renders correctly and as supposed:

```
<!-- Content Page Structure -->
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
           <!-- here i have some long text which should span for the whole page width, 
                however it doesnt and expands for a little more than 1/3 of it -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <ul class="pricing-table"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <ul class="pricing-table"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <ul class="pricing-table"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
           <!-- here i have some long text which should span for the whole page width, 
                however it doesnt and expands for a little more than 1/3 of it -->
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my bad, here I found the solution:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/35621-foundation-5-not-rendering-on-mobile